The dual of a subspace of a normed space $E$ is isometric to a subspace of $E'$
Let $E$ be a normed vector space and $F\subset E$ be a subspace of $E$. I want to show that there's a bounded linear operator $T:F'\to E'$ such that given $f\in F'$, $T(f)$ is an extension of $f$ and $||T(f)||=||f||$. This would imply that $T$ is an isometry between $F'$ and and the image of $T$.
The book I'm reading suggest to take $T(f)$ some hahn-banch extension of $f$, but it's not clear to me that $T$ is linear. (since the extension in this case is not unique in general)
I thought about using an argument similar to the proof of the hahn-banach theorem, by defining $\mathcal{P}$ as the set of all bounded linear operators $T:F'\to C(T)'$ , where $C(T)\subset E$ is a subspace such that $f\in F'$, $T(f)$ is an extension of $f$ and $||T(f)||=||f||$. I defined a partial order where $T\le S$ if $S(f)$ extends $T(f)$ and $C(T)\subset C(S)$. The idea was to use the Zorn Lemma to show that $\mathcal{P}$ has a maximal element $T$ and try to show that $C(T)=E$. I supposed $C(T)\ne E$ and took $x_0\in E-C(T)$. However I got stuck in defining $\widetilde T:F'\to(C(T)\oplus[x_0])'$ such that $T\le\widetilde T$.
Maybe there's a simpler way that I missed or my attempt need a little more detailing.

Are you sure that this result is true? The dual of a subspace is isometric to a quotient of the dual, not subspace. Fot example, $\ell_1$ is isometric to a subspace of $C([0,1])$ but its dual $\ell_{\infty} = \ell_1'$ is not isometric to a subspace of $M([0,1]) = C([0,1])'$.
